# Multiple IIS website deployment using Azure DevOps task IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have a template for IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup. I am running a pipeline to use this task. I am able to create IIS website using this scenario. But Now I have to deploy like 50 website and pipeline would be very big. is there anyway we can handle this kinda scenario ?

**template**

```
- ${{ each w in s.website }}:
            - task: IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup@0
              displayName: deploy ${{ w.WebsiteName }}
              inputs:
                IISDeploymentType: '${{ w.IISDeploymentType }}'
                ActionIISWebsite: 'CreateOrUpdateWebsite'
                WebsiteName: '${{ w.WebsiteName }}'
                WebsitePhysicalPath: '${{ w.WebsitePhysicalPath }}'
                WebsitePhysicalPathAuth: 'WebsiteUserPassThrough'
                AddBinding: true
                Bindings:  '{"bindings":[{"protocol":"${{ w.bindingProtocol }}","ipAddress":"${{ w.bindingIP }}","port":"${{ w.bindingPort }}","hostname":"${{ w.bindingHostname }}","sslThumbprint":"${{ w.bindingSslThumbprint }}","sniFlag":${{ w.bindingSniFlag }}}]}'
                CreateOrUpdateAppPoolForWebsite: true
                AppPoolNameForWebsite: '${{ w.appPoolNameForWebsite }}'                
                DotNetVersionForWebsite: 'v4.0'
                PipeLineModeForWebsite: 'Integrated'
                AppPoolIdentityForWebsite: '${{ w.appPoolIdentityForWebsite }}'                
                AppPoolUsernameForWebsite: '${{ w.appPoolUsername }}'
                AppPoolPasswordForWebsite: '${{ w.appPoolPassword }}'
```

**Pipeline step**

```
jobs: 
  - job: 
  - template: IaC/templates/IIS-website-configure.yml@templates
    website:
            - IISDeploymentType: 'IISWebsite'
              appPoolIdentityForWebsite: 'SpecificUser' # other options would be ApplicationPoolIdentity, LocalService, LocalSystem, or NetworkService
              bindingProtocol: 'https' # other option would be https - Select HTTP for the website to have an HTTP binding, or select HTTPS for the website to have a Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) binding.
              appPoolUsername: '$(USR_RU_Core)' # if using AppPoolIdentityForWebsite=SpecificUser
              appPoolPassword: '$(PWD_RU_Core)' # if using AppPoolIdentityForWebsite=SpecificUser
              bindingSslThumbprint: '$(THUMBPRINT_Dev)' # if using https - Provide the thumb-print of the Secure Socket Layer certificate that the website is going to use for the HTTPS communication as a 40 character long hexadecimal string. The SSL certificate should be already installed on the Computer, at Local Computer, Personal store.
              bindingSniFlag: 'false' # if using https - Set the option to true to set the Server Name Indication (SNI) for the website. SNI extends the SSL and TLS protocols to indicate the host name that the clients are attempting to connect to. It allows, multiple secure websites with different certificates, to use the same IP address.
              bindingHostname: '' # required if bindingSniFlag = true - Enter a host name (or domain name) for the website. If a host name is specified, then the clients must use the host name instead of the IP address to access the website.
              WebsiteName: 'core-xxx.xxxxx.net'
              WebsitePhysicalPath: '%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot\core-xxx.xxxx.net'
              bindingIP: '172.xx.xx.xx'
              bindingPort: '443'
```